# Create button in declared variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of images for faded out and faded in i.e when an image is selected others become faded. It is working. Whenever an image is selected some information about that picture is shown beside list of images. It is also working. But at present I need a button in that text which will be different for every picture. Can any one guide me how to do this? 
For text, in script there is a variable which contains text as array, like-

```
var line = [{
    "caption": "Violet",
    "content": "It is 1st color of VIBGYOR.",
}, {
    "caption": "Blue",
    "content": "It is third color of VIBGYOR."
}, {
    "caption": "Orange",
    "content": "It is sixth color of VIBGYOR."
}]
```

And the function is:

```
function motionStart(e, data) {
    $(".title, .text", this).hide().removeClass('animated fadeInDown fadeInUp');
}

function motionEnd(e, data) {

    var text = line[data.index % line.length];
    $(".title, .text", this).show();

    $(".title", this).text(text.caption).addClass('animated fadeInDown');
    $(".text", this).text(text.content).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
}

function carouselCreated(e, data) {
    motionEnd.call(this, e, data)
}
```

I want to insert `document.write('<button type="button">Click Me!</button>')` for each. after clicking button it will show another page.
Please help if possible.

Comment: Please take some time to properly indent and format your code.

Comment: Question is not clear. You can create a demo fiddle to make is more expressive.

Comment: Instead of `.text()`, you can create a HTML string using caption and set it using `.html()`

Comment: Actually I'm editing a code of a template. I am beginner in js. I know how to create html button in js. But i am unable to do it for given code. in array declaration how to write button declaration?

Comment: You can try something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pf92wvc2/)

Comment: <div style="bottom: 0px; position: absolute; text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 40px; display: block; color: #334081; font-weight: bold" class="title">title text</div>
        </div>
It is written in html for caption. There is also a line like this for content. So for button text what I have to write, can you tell me that? @Rajesh

Comment: @SGhosh can you create a JSFiddle? That would be easier for all of us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using JQuery.

You can use:

```
var button = $('<button type="button">' + someJsVar + '</button>');
```

then append it to the dom:

```
$('body').append(button);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where to write this?

Comment: you can add it to the DOM after `$(document).ready(function() { //some code to run after document has loaded  });`

Comment: where to define the button??

Comment: Wherever...? that line of creating dom with jquery works wherever jquery is in scope.